# Trying to add '- character in the df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The below code should display rows with  '-  as a DateOFBirth regardless of the today's date and the date in the past(value of **x**). So, for **x** equal to 6 the result should be:

```
No of days: 6
    Name DateOFBirth
0    Dan  26/03/2020
1  Brian  23/03/2020
2    Gig          '-
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Dan','Brian','Marie','Gig'],'DateOFBirth': ['26/03/2020','23/03/2020','12/02/2018',"'-"]})
df['DateOFBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOFBirth'],format='%d/%m/%Y',errors='ignore')

x = input ("No of days: ")

today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
result = today - timedelta(days=int(x)+1)


output = df[(df['DateOFBirth'] =="'-")  or  (df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today)]
df = output

print(df)
```

The **error** is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use  `|` instead `or`

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: same error?  line of error?

Comment: Same error. Line 13.

Comment: could you try run `(df['DateOFBirth'] =="'-")  |  (df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today)` and show the output?

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: try : `df['DateOFBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOFBirth'],format='%d/%m/%Y',errors='coerce')` and then `output = df[(df['DateOFBirth'].isnull())  |  ((df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today))]`

Comment: `output['DateOFBirth'] = output['DateOFBirth'].fillna("'-")` if you want keep it

Comment: @ansev, you rock! I see the correct output, but I don't understand from where hour:min:sec is added. This is what I get now : Dan  2020-03-26 00:00:00

Comment: @MMarie Is that output from your index? If you don't want the time you can use `.dt.date` on `df.index` or the column where you only want to keep the dates.

Comment: @Jason I tried to apply `.dt.date` for the line with `output = ...dt.date` and I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt' `

Comment: You need to apply it to a `DateTime` object, if you do `df.info()` you get a list of your column types and your index type. Look the column containing your dates (or look at the index type if your dates are in the index). Then use `.dt.date` on the column/index as appropriate.